# Add data to chart properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Hey folks I have a task to show user data on the chart (I'm using [react-native slide charts](https://github.com/connectedcars/react-native-slide-charts)) but it becomes a little bit tricky.
So what I'm trying to achieve is next:
I'm making a request and get the next data from the server:

```
{
  "trend": [92, 93, 94, 94, 93, 93, 94, 95, 95, 95, 95, 94, 96, 95, 96],
  "history": [1087, 112, 117, 190, 153, 163, 138, 166, 191, 191, 187, 163, 187, 177, 109, 107, 196, 175, 113, 192, 113, 112, 169, 109, 109, 157, 126, 170, 137, 146, 132, 114],
}
```

And I know that `trend` is data for the last 15 minutes with an interval of 1 min, and the `history` is data for the last 8 hours with an interval of 15 mins.

I need to map this data and show it on the chart. I'm trying to do the next:

```
const initialDateTime = dayjs();

const mappedTrend = data.trend.reverse().map((el, i) => ({
      x: i === 0 ? initialDateTime.valueOf() : initialDateTime.add(i * 1, 'minutes').valueOf(),
      y: el,
}));

const mappedHistory = data.history.reverse().map((el, i) => ({
      x: i === 0 ? initialDateTime.valueOf() : initialDateTime.add(i * 15, 'minutes').valueOf(),
      y: el,
}));
```

in output I have 2 arrays like `{x: timestamp, y: value}`;

Then I'm adding it to the state and the chart looks at this data:

```
setState({data: [...mappedHistory, ...mapTrend]})
```

seems like it is ok till here, but now, for example, I need to load more data, after for example 5 minutes I can make another request and will get almost the same data but with different numbers, and I need now, to prolong the chart data with a new one, but how to do it? How to add data properly?

I prepared a [snack here](https://snack.expo.dev/@dorado13/react-native-slide-charts-dd)
Problems are, the chart is looking quirky and when new data comes it also shows strange. And the thing is, on chart data should be in range on 24h that's why I use `xRange` on the chart.
So any ideas on how to solve this or fix it?

Comment: Just want to double check, do you want to append the new data onto the data you just got?

Comment: @MarkBarton yes, I guess I should merge it somehow or so

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to combine the data currently being kept in your state, you can spread the existing array with the incoming array;

```
updateArray = (mappedHistory, mapTrend) => {
   const newArray =  [...mappedHistory, ...mapTrend];
   this.setState({ data: [...this.state.data, ...newArray] });
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not exactly what I need

Comment: had a wee typo in there. Meant to do this.state.data. Sorrry, haven't worked with class based components for ages! I would recommend looking at Function components in the future by the way. Much easier to use!

Comment: functional or class in this particular example not really means a lot. the task is abstract. I need to add new data to the chart.

Comment: it was just an aside, David. However, your implementation looks like it's going to be heavy on the side-effects which could be causing you issues. Your timeout at 1200ms will overwrite the state change at timeout 5000 ms. Considering both of these timeouts are doing the same thing. Why not call this.getNewData() in both of them? Or forgo the 5000ms timeout for the 1200ms timeout.